# Not able to view few fields in campaign object in workbench

Tags: campaign, workbench, field-level-security, system-admin

I am trying to enable the `field-level permission` of few fields of the `Campaign` object in salesforce so that I can view them in `workbench` but unfortunately, after enabling the field level access it is not showing there.

I have a `System Admin profile`

Screenshot of `field level visibility`

[image]

System admin profile campaign object setting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The release notes only has information that says these fields will be available on page layouts.

[image: Snapshot from Release Notes]

Even the campaign object reference does not include these fields: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_campaign.htm

Comment: Does it mean , I won't be able to refer it in workbench ? As eventually I want to transfer these filed value to different org

Comment: Hunt, I can only see so much information from the documentation. I am not 100% sure either.